# What is the item level requirement of MoP dungeons?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I haven't been playing for a while so my gear is not up to date, and I want to make sure that I am ready to sign up for MoP dungeons from the start.

So I would like to know what is the minimum item level requirement for the dungeons in Mists of Pandaria?

Most importantly 'Stormstout Brewery' and 'Temple of the Jade Serpent' so I know what item level of gear I need to get before release.

Comment: I know you said you want to get into MoP dungeoning straight away, but it's probably worthwhile to note as well that the Pandaria starter quests will probably offer gear rewards with an iLvl appropriate to let you queue for MoP dungeons. So remember that is you're struggling to get gear before the release :)

Comment: The green gear offered by starting area vendor are ilevel 382 if I recall correct, LFR gear is 384, so I might as well go do some LFR, but based on the answer I got no problem even though I have only done LFR a couple of times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stormstout Brewery and Temple of the Jade Serpent both require ilvl 358 as a minimum.

[image]

The list from [here](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/zone/#expansion=4&type=dungeons) includes:

Ilvl 358:

- Stormstout Brewery
- Temple of the
  Jade Serpent

Ilvl 393:

- Mogu'shan Palace
- Shado-Pan Monastery

Ilvl 435:

- Gate of the Setting Sun
- Siege of Niuzao Temple
- Other heroics

Comment: nice, do you have the iLevel for the other 2 leveling dungeons and the level 90 normal/heroic?

Comment: Added those from Battle.net's site.

Comment: as of the recent hotfix, heroic ilevel requirement is now 435